# Compatibility level upgrade from 100 to 130, "Query Optimizer Fixes" flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've just migrated a DB from an old 2008 sql server to a new 2016 server. I had it running in Compatibility lvl 100 for a while, all being fine. I've ran upgrade adviser and nothing was flagged also tested the system out in a test environment with 130 level set ..all good.

I've since done the switch in prodcution , CPU load is slightly above the norm, not sure if this will correct it self over time once new plans with the new CE are being created.. Also spotted an option "Query Optimizer Fixes" what will enabling this flag do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms,Microsoft used to release hotfixes to query optimizer in form of trace flags,with each fix having its own trace flag..

Say for example,if you had below issue

> Error message when you perform an update operation by using a cursor in SQL Server 2005: "Transaction (Process ID ) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim"

Microsoft released a HotFix for this,under some trace flag 4120..

So to apply this fix,you would have to enable trace flag like below

> DBCC TRACEON (4120,-1)

Imagine for a moment,enabling trace flags for all hotfixes,that would be cubersome.so Microsoft  ,from SQL2005,came up with a single trace flag 4199 which covers all Optimizer related fixes

Customers can enable this single  trace flag ,if they saw  any optimizer related issues .This practice also shielded other customers,since only customers who saw issues used to apply this trace flag..

With SQL2016,SQLServer removed this trace flag and came up with this database scoped configuration.

Enabling this option will help you in getting latest query optimizer fixes and the best part is this can enabled at database level as opposed to trace flags,which always acts at server level..

Microsoft Recommends below on enabling this traceflag:

> Trace flag 4199 is recommended only for customers who are seeing specific performance issues, customers are advised to remove trace flag 4199 after they migrate their databases to the latest compatibility level because trace flag 4199 will be reused for future fixes that may not apply to your application and could cause unexpected plan performance changes on a production system

In this case Traceflag 4199 equates to Query Optimizer Fixes option

**References  :**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974006/sql-server-query-optimizer-hotfix-trace-flag-4199-servicing-model

Comment: so would you recommend turning it on then? How long would it take to get all the optimized fixes? One sprocs runtime has gone from under 1 sec to 1:48 secs.. I've enabled the old traceflag on it for the time being

Comment: ,Microsoft releases hotfixes for any issues ,if your issue relates to issue described in hotfix,then you can turn it on.mostly these hitfixes will be also included in service packs and cumulative updates

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR** If you are using SQL Server 2016 and your compatibility level is set to SQL Server 2016 (130), you can ignore this safely. You can set it on or off, it does not matter.  **Safe choice is leave it off**

---

I have been searching for answers to this question as well.  There are several posts that have a shorter version of [the answer by TheGameiswar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42632059/2112418) that don't go into detail.

The Microsoft words about it are fairly brief.

> Enable or disable “QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES” at the database level, to take advantage of the latest query optimizer hotfixes, regardless of the compatibility level of the database. This is equivalent to Trace Flag 4199 [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34718.new-sql-server-2016-scoped-configuration.aspx)

The clearest answer I found is by Dave Pinal in his post [SQL SERVER – Database Scoped Configurations – Query Optimizer Fixes](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/08/10/sql-server-database-scoped-configurations-query-optimizer-fixes/)

> Before SQL Server 2016, whenever any hotfix or cumulative updates were released, query optimizer improvements were not automatically effective in SQL Server.
>
> However, beginning with SQL Server 2016, all the query optimizer improves are now based on compatibility level.
>
> If you are using SQL Server 2016 and your compatibility level is set to SQL Server 2016 (130), you can ignore this safely. You can set it on or off, it does not matter.

[SQL Server query optimizer hotfix trace flag 4199 servicing model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974006/sql-server-query-optimizer-hotfix-trace-flag-4199-servicing-model)

> In SQL Server 2016, trace flag 4199 hotfixes that are made to previous releases of SQL Server will become enabled under database COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 130 without trace flag 4199 enabled.
>
> The latest compatibility level already enables all previous fixes under trace flag 4199. This means that upgrading a database to the latest compatibility level and removing trace flag 4199 still enables all fixes

On a final note, the following sentence at the trace flag 4199 page suggests that new hot fixes may require 4199 or "Query Optimizer Fixes" = ON to become effective.  Testing a new database build in SQL 2017 (CU13) {compatibility 140} finds the value OFF by default.

> Trace flag 4199 will be used to release any future SQL Server 2016 hotfixes for databases by using the 130 compatibility level.

Comment: Right.  Database Compatibility Level now controls the Query Optimizer behavior, in addition to the TSQL parser.  If you want to de-couple them use the QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES database option to opt in for the latest Query Optimizer behavior without the other behavior changes controlled by the Database Compatibility Level.